# DOMPDF: br tag causes text to justify

Tags: php, dompdf

Getting a weird problem with DOMPDF..

Wherever I use content with a br tag in it..

```
<p>
Something<br/>
Something Else<br/>
Last line
</p>
```

The rendered output pdf seems to justify the line where the br tag is so it spans across the whole width.

Anyone get that too? Any idea how to prevent it?

I'm on the latest version from the trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uh - thought I'd try that but obviously not.

If i explicitly see the P style to text-align:left that fixes it.